# Android line chart - same x axis required as new entry?

Tags: android, kotlin, linechart

[image]

Here x axis 0  have 3 values (0,10),(0,20),(0,120).
my case i needs each data as separate entry.

That means x-0 will show 3 times in the graph.Now all y axis in combined into same x .How to achieve that?.  is it possible?

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/line_chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    />
```

code

```
 private var list = arrayListOf<Entry>()
 list.add(Entry(0,10))
 list.add(Entry(0,20))
 list.add(Entry(0,120))
 Collections.sort(list, EntryXComparator())
 val set = LineDataSet(list, "label name")

 val dataSets =ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
 dataSets.add(set)
 val data = LineData(dataSets)
 line_chart.data = data
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library, but looks like you need a separate LineDataSet for each line you want to show separately on the graph.

Perhaps ask the library author if such thing is supported.